# Plotting in Matlab pmf vs actual frequency

Tags: matlab, plot

Hi I have this code which generates a DNA sequence but I would like to plot the empirical frequency of each symbol vs the pmf of X which is {0.1,0.5,0.3,0.1}.

```
n = 10;
bases = {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'};
probs = [0.1,0.5,0.3,0.1];
seq = bases(discretize(rand(1,n),[0,cumsum(probs)]));
disp(strjoin(seq))
```

I am sorry I know this is basic stuff but I can't seem to figure it out and I only have been using Matlab for about a week.

Comment: Do you really mean _versus_ (one axis is pmf, the other empirical frequency), or _in addition_ (one axis is bases, the other is pmf or freq)? If it is _versus_, what happens when two bases have the same pmf value?

Comment: I have to verify the empirical frequency of each symbol in the string is close to its probability by plotting frequency versus the pmf of x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this is the most efficient method, but it's the simplest thing that came to mind and it should work for your case.

```
n = 10;
bases = {'A', 'C', 'G', 'T'};
probs = [0.1,0.5,0.3,0.1];
seq = bases(discretize(rand(1,n),[0,cumsum(probs)]));
strseq = strjoin(seq);
freq = zeros(1,4);
for i=1:4
    freq(i) = sum(strseq==bases{i});
end

figure
scatter(probs,freq);
```

Matlab allows you to do some nifty things with indexing and comparing values in arrays. The instruction

```
strseq==bases{i}
```

returns a binary array of the same length as strseq and whose components take the value 1 if the letter at the corresponding position in strseq coincides with the letter bases{i} and 0 otherwise. This allows you to index only the values in array that obey a specific criterion and you can of course do the same thing with other comparison operators such as ~=,<,>,<=,>=. A neat side effect is that it also allows to easily count the elements obeying that given criterion.

Comment: Thank you for your help I'll try it out